# External website & goal setup in FXM doesn't show in Experience Analytics

Tags: experience-analytics, fxm

I've added a subdomain (not the sitecore site) in `FXM` and Sitecore was able to find its beacon in the tracking script section with this message `JavaScript beacon found on the external website`.

Next, I attached a Sitecore goal to a link on the homepage of the subdomain via FXM's experience editor and published it accordingly.

To test if the goal triggered as expected, I clicked on the link twice but nothing was captured in Experience Analytics when I looked at it the next day.

Then, I found some suggestions online that I need to add the following to the configuration section of the external website item in FXM to make it work:

1) **Matching rule** - `where request domain is <external website>`.

2) **Language Rules** - `Set the language of the visit to the default Sitecore language`.

However, I am still getting the same result, nothing shows in Experience Analytics.

What did I miss? BTW, I'm using Sitecore 9.0.2.

Thank you,

Roman

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up rules for tracking. I faced the same issue then I write match rule to allow the external website request.

**Set up rules for tracking:**

In the Marketing Control Panel, you can set up the `Federated Experience Manager` to track only certain types of visits to your website, for example, visits from specific domains or visits referred from a specific website.

**To set up rules for tracking the visits to an external website:**

1. On the Sitecore Launchpad, open the Marketing Control Panel and in
   the content tree, navigate to Federated Experience Manager.
2. Click the external website that you want to apply a new rule to.
3. Under the Configuration section, in the Matching Rules section, click the link Edit 
   rule, and in the Rule Set Editor
   dialog, add the relevant rules and actions.

[image]

Comment: Hi Himmat, I did as mentioned in point 1. Instead of request referrer, I was using request domain. Any difference ?

Comment: @Roman Sorry updated it. I did with the request domain matching rule.

Comment: In Sitecore 9.01 I remember rules that identify referer and domain from request were no longer working. They refer to non existing assembly in 9. See https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/some-sitecore-8-conditions-for-conditional-renderings-seem-missing-in-sitecore-9/14512#14512

So maybe double check the rule's definition of the rule that you are using, whether it actually has an implementation in SC9

Comment: Thanks @Joost for your info and link. It seems a little tricky for my issue as it happens in FXM instead of Experience Analytics. When I setup the matching rule in FXM, it only allows me to select rules under "Federated Experience Manager - Domain Matching" and nothing else. The same happens to language rules as well where I can only pick rules from "Federated Experience Manager - Domain Tracking" only.